# QML: horizontal flickable visually lingers in StackView

Tags: qt, user-interface, animation, qml

Suppose you have a long horizontal content, so you put it in flickable for your user to swipe through. This might be a picture or a graph or something else. When the content is swiped right so that it's left side is hidden, and you pop the page from stack, a stack animation occurs where all the content is moved right. However, the before hidden part of flickable content then slides to the right also and becomes visible until the animation is over. I want to find a way to prevent this.

Here is the picture of a red rectangle lingering, carefully captured at 25 frames per second:

[image]

Here is the minimal example code to illustrate the problem:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    header: ToolBar {
        contentHeight: toolButton.implicitHeight

        ToolButton {
            id: toolButton
            text: "<"
            onClicked: {
                stackView.pop()
            }
        }
    }

    StackView {
        id: stackView
        initialItem: pageZero
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    Component {
        id: pageZero

        Column {
            Label {
                text: "Page zero"
            }
            Button {
                text: "next"
                onClicked: { stackView.push(pageOne) }
            }
        }
    }
    Component {
        id: pageOne

        Flickable {
            height: 200
            width: 200
            contentHeight: 200
            contentWidth: 300

            Rectangle {
                height: 200
                width: 300
                color: "red"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The question is, what handlers should i put to hide the flickable *before* the animation starts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, i found how, actually this solution wasn't that hard. (= What i need to do is to have my flickable hidden during the transition, and also shown after the transition has ended, so I add the two lines:

```
        Flickable {
            height: 200
            width: 200
            contentHeight: 200
            contentWidth: 300
            // watch this next line
            StackView.onDeactivating: {rect.visible = false}
            StackView.onActivating: {rect.visible = true}

            Rectangle {
                id: rect
                height: 200
                width: 300
                color: "red"
            }
        }
```